# Mouse left button ('5' key on numeric keypad) does not work

Tags: centos, mouse

I often use keyboard shortcuts rather than the mouse, use mouse keys and then click button (keypad 5) do not work. **How can I use mousekey click button?**
Still mousekey of the Shortcut Menu key (mouse right click function) does work.

I'm using CentOS 8.

Comment: Mousekeys has always worked fine for me in Windows 7 and 10. Does it work for you on other machines? There may be something on your specific PC that's overriding the key binding. Please provide more info.

Comment: I forgot the os: that is the Centos8. What is the key overriding(how it works?)..

Comment: I've added the CentOS tag to your question. I can't help with this, but hopefully someone else can.

Comment: Have you tried it with Num Lock on and also off?

Comment: Surely, mouse key has been used with num lock off. mouse pointer always on the screen but no clicks is problematic...

Comment: Is there any way to override to the key(number keypad 5) ?